# Mosaic view for temporary playlist

Tags: spotify

If I create temporary playlist, add tracks to it manually and then try to use it as the source of an image view as per :

```js
var imageForPlaylist = imageView.forPlaylist(playlist, { height: 300, widht: 300 });
```

the result is always a placeholder (the quaver image).

Is this expected behaviour?

Comment: Experiencing same issue too with `Preview API 1.0`.

Answer (score 2):

You should see a mosaic image. Try this code, that generates a temporary playlist with 10 tracks:

```js
(function () {
  "use strict";
  var sp = getSpotifyApi(),
    models = sp.require("$api/models"),
    views = sp.require("$api/views"),
    container = document.getElementById('container');

  var tempPlaylist = new models.Playlist();
  var playlistUri = 'spotify:user:nowplaylist:playlist:6QHyDeqaPNZ0nyLFJbSKTL';
  models.Playlist.fromURI(playlistUri, function (playlist) {
    for (var i = 0, l = Math.min(10, playlist.length); i < l; i++) {
      var track = playlist.get(i);
      tempPlaylist.add(track);
    }
  });

  var player = new views.Player();
  player.context = tempPlaylist;
  container.appendChild(player.node);
})();
```

and renders this `Image` with player:

[image: Player for a temporary playlist]

Comment: I should have been clearer. I am using the preview api, v 1.0 - there is no Player view.

Comment: That seems to be still 'not-implemented`, as stated here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17477655/spotify-api-1-0-0-get-image-of-playlist-of-given-set-of-tracks