# Spotify App API: Creating a player of top tracks from an artist

Tags: javascript, jquery, api, spotify, spotify-app

I am having difficulties with both Toplists and Image right now and I am hoping that someone can help me. Essentially, all I want to do is create a player and playlist with an artists top tracks. I have tried using search since I can't get the desired behaviour out of Toplists, but that hasn't bought me any closer so I thought I'd ask here.

Essentially, the functionality should:

1. Take an artist name or artist id
2. Find that artists top 10 tracks
3. Create a new temporary playlist and add the 10 tracks
4. Create and insert a player and a playlist

This would seem pretty easy, but it's driving me a little nuts.

Comment: Might be better to post your toplist code and we can see what's wrong with it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [`Toplist.forArtist`](https://developer.spotify.com/docs/apps/api/1.0/api-toplists-toplist.html#forArtist) function for fetching the top 10 tracks by an artist.

The following code fetches the first 10 top tracks for an artist and renders a list view and a player:

```
require(['$api/toplists#Toplist', '$views/list#List', '$views/image#Image'],
  function(Toplist, List, Image) {

  var artist = models.Artist.fromURI('spotify:artist:2qk9voo8llSGYcZ6xrBzKx');
  var toplist = Toplist.forArtist(artist);

  // fetch the 10 most played tracks
  toplist.tracks.snapshot(0, 10).done(function(tracks) {

    // create temporary playlist
    models.Playlist
      .createTemporary('myTempList')
      .done(function(playlist){ 
        playlist.load('tracks').done(function(){
          for (var i = 0, l = tracks.length; i < l; i++) {
              var track = tracks.get(i);
              playlist.tracks.add(track);
          }

          // append a list view
          var listWrapper = document.getElementById('list-wrapper');
          var list = List.forPlaylist(playlist);
          listWrapper.appendChild(list.node);
          list.init();

          // append a player
          // note that you might have a grey placeholder
          // see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17477655
          var playerWrapper = document.getElementById('player-wrapper');
          var player = Image.forPlaylist(playlist, {player: true});
          playerWrapper.appendChild(player.node);
      });
    });
  });
});
```

The JS code refers to 2 placeholders that will contain the views:

```
    <div id="list-wrapper"></div>
    <div id="player-wrapper"></div>
```

Note that due to a problem with [mosaic cover images for temporary playlist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17477655/spotify-api-1-0-0-get-image-of-playlist-of-given-set-of-tracks) you may need to replace the default cover placeholder with another image.

Comment: Do you happen to have a link to change the player image to a custom jpeg?

Comment: You would do something like `var player = Image.fromSource('img/image.png', {playerItem: playlist, player: true});
playerWrapper.appendChild(player.node);`

Answer (score -1):

Unfortunately, it appears you'll have to brute-force it.

- Get all tracks by the artist, either by:

  - iterating all of the [Artist's](https://developer.spotify.com/docs/apps/api/1.0/api-models-artist.html) albums, appearances, compilations, singles and collecting all the tracks
  - Use the poorly-documented-but-probably-easy-to-guess [Search](https://developer.spotify.com/docs/apps/api/1.0/api-search-search.html) module and search for the artist, hopefully getting all their tracks.  Here's the [advanced search docs](https://support.spotify.com/us/learn-more/faq/#!/article/Advanced-search1/?in=search)
- Retrieve the popularity of all the tracks
- Find the ten highest popularity tracks

Comment: I was going to work up some sample code, but eww, I don't think you'll go this route.  Perhaps http://www.last.fm/api/show/artist.getTopTracks would be a better choice?  Though you'd then have to use echonest's rosetta to convert MBID to a spotify uri.

Comment: Note for the downvoter - my answer was based on my impression that the asker did not want to use the artist's top tracks.